# How to get rid of app.php in Symfony2 URIs with Nginx

Tags: symfony, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to get a clear understanding of what's going on with my nginx configuration file for Symfony2, here it is:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        autoindex on;
        server_name example.com;
        root /var/www/example.com/web;

        rewrite ^/app\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

        location / {
            index app.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ @symfony;
        }

        location @symfony {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
        }

        location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        }
}
```

In short, I'm trying to strip app.php in every possible URI that a user can set e.g. example.com/app.php/demo or just example.com/app.php.

This config actually works for URIs like ones above, but it leads to a redirect loop in case of trying to access "root" URI example.com.

And if I remove $uri/ from try_files and leave only $uri and a fallback @symfony there, everything is working fine except I can't access any directories as they're going to be processed by SF.

I'm out of ideas, did a lot of research on how nginx and rewrites actually work, but as for now it's a dead end for me. If you can find a solution to stay with $uri/ in try_files and get out of a loop at front, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This solution from [Nginx Tips](http://www.nginxtips.com/nginx-configuration-for-symfony-framework/) worked for me. It's almost, but not quite, the same as yours.

```
server {
server_name domain.tld www.domain.tld;
root /var/www/project/web;

location / {
# try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}

location @rewriteapp {
# rewrite all to app.php
rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
}

location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config).php(/|$) {
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.*)$;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
}

error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem with this configuration is that it doesn't have $uri/ in location / {} block, and I need $uri/ because I may have some user-specific folders with yet unknown names, that should be accessible (they may contain other apps for example). Also, it doesn't really cut app.php from any URI that could be explicitly set by the user ;)